# API connection HTTP 400

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to connect to an API using post request (requests python library).

You can find the code below :

```
myurl = 'http://my/endpoint/url'
mydata = {'username':'*****',
         'password':'********'}
myheaders = {'content-type':'application/json', 
             'Accept':'application/json'}


response = requests.post(url = myurl, data = mydata, headers= myheaders)
print(response.status_code)
```

However my response status code returns 400. 
How can I find what I am doing wrong ?

The instructions for the connection are the following :[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

my_auth=HTTPBasicAuth('<username>', '<password>')
payload = {'some_key1:': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
requests.post(URL, json=json.dumps(payload), auth=my_auth)
```

It work if the Rest API supports Basic authentication, if not refer https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ for other type of authentication.

Comment: Thank you. The type of authentication seems to be RestAuthentication according to the instructions. But it does not mention this type of authentication on your website.

Answer (score 0):

4xx http response is client error, so you should check our request info.
(Header, Cookie, Data, ...)

If you are crawling some data from url (http://my/endpoint/url), it is good to use google development tools or charles proxy, you can check whether your request is correct or not.